# CASE statement in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case

i have a problem with CASE sintax (I think) and I hope you can help me. I'll try to explain my problem:

I have 2 fields DV_CODE e DV_NAME  and I would like to have DV_NAME = 'Other person' if I haven't the code, that means DV_CODE = null

This is my code:

```
SELECT rep_code,
   name,
   act_date,
   dv_code,
   CASE
      WHEN DUAL_CODE_AM IS NULL THEN DV_NAME= 'Other person'
      WHEN DUAL_CODE_PM IS NULL THEN DV_NAME= 'Other person'
   END
   AS dv_name
  ......
```

(in my case "else"statment is useless)

but system returns to me 2 errors:

or: missing keyword
or: missing parenthesis

thanks in advance.

Comment: Case EXPRESSION, not case statement...

Comment: I lost the first phrase: "Hi guys, nice to read you again"

Comment: You mention in your question you want to check `DV_CODE IS null`, but then in your sample code you check `DUAL_CODE_AM IS NULL` and `DUAL_CODE_PM` ?? so what are you checking for NULL? `DV_CODE`, `DUAL_CODE_AM`, or `DUAL_CODE_PM` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is the "correct code": SELECT rep_code,
   name,
   act_date,
   
   CASE
      WHEN DUAL_CODE_AM IS NULL THEN DV_NAME= 'Other person'
      WHEN DUAL_CODE_PM IS NULL THEN DV_NAME= 'Other person'
   END
   AS dv_name
  ......
i check if one of DUAL_CODE_AM OR DUAL_CODE_PM are NULL

Comment: @Solido you can edit your question and add this new snippet.

Comment: corrected! 
I want NAME field set to "Other person" if and only if DUAL_CODE_AM OR DUAL_CODE_PM are NULL

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT rep_code,
   name,
   act_date,
   CASE
      WHEN DUAL_CODE_AM IS NULL THEN 'Other person'
      WHEN DUAL_CODE_PM IS NULL THEN 'Other person'
   END
   AS dv_name
  ......
```